# Android Device Monitor can't open

Tags: android

I find that I can't open the Android Device Monitor through Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor.

Instead, I got an error "JVM terminated. Exit code=1 /usr/bin/java  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m   -Xms512m   -Xmx1024m  ...". This seems to be happened since I update the Android Studio to 2.3.

What's more, When I go to the SDK > tools, the Hierarchy Viewer is gone.

[image]

Comment: can you print screen the error you get ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes. Please see the pic above.

Comment: verify your Java/JDK/Jre installation path. Make sure it is correct.

Comment: Mine is like this:  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111  
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre

Comment: Are you using ubuntu ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes. I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: open your terminal and type `echo $JRE_HOME`, what you see ?

Comment: I can see the jre path

Comment: what is the full path ?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/jre

Comment: I run "java -version", "javac","java", they all functioning well.

Comment: Follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/175547/6428890),make sure you wrote the path correctly.

Comment: But I think mine is correct because the "javac" works well.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-JAVA_HOME-on-Ubuntu/answer/Denis-Kalinin?srid=NDEi

Comment: Thx a lot. I move my enviroment from the bashrc file to the profile and it works.But why does it have no hierarchy viewer in the monitor?

Comment: I don't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify your `Java/JDK/Jre` installation path.
2. Put JAVA_HOME in `/etc/profile` instead of `bashrc` file.